# Is a semi join considered a left or right join?

Tags: sql

This is a really basic question, but is a semi-join the same as a left or a right join?

That is: when someone says

> Lets show all users by country. We need to do a semi-join because some countries have no users

Does he refer to just doing either a left or right join?

Comment: I think they are refering to an outer join

Answer (score 8):

A semi-join is the set of *tuples* in one table that match the join keys of the second.  Unlike inner and outer joins, a semi-join cannot multiply the number of rows in the table: a tuple is either included or not included.

By definition, when the table with the matched tuples is the first table, then it is called a left semi-join.  If it were the second, then it would be a right semi-join.  This usage is exactly analogous to left and right outer joins.  But with the difference that rows (tuples) are filtered for a semi-join but not an outer join.  The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_.28.E2.8B.89.29.28.E2.8B.8A.29) article on relational algebra has a good illustration.

Personally, I don't find the set based description particularly useful.  A left semi join is equivalent to an `in` query in SQL:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.key in (select u.key from u);
```